# MySQL syntax error using LIMIT command with Prepared Statement in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-limit

I am writing code in Java and I want to take every time I run this code the next line from a MySQL table.The second time I run this code is this.

```
String timh1 = "1";
String timh2 = "2";
PreparedStatement st = null;
String sqlGrammes = "SELECT SURNAME ,KATHGORIA, AFM , NAME FROM EMPLOYEE LIMIT ?,? ";
try {
    st = connection.prepareStatement(sqlGrammes);
    st.setString(1, timh1);
    st.setString(2, timh2);
```

But it shows me this error :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1','2'' at line 1

Comment: Looks like you can't parametrize the limit values.

Comment: maybe this , but why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`limit` accepts integer parameters, so you should use `int`s, not `String`s:

```
int timh1 = 1;
int timh2 = 2;
PreparedStatement st = null;
String sqlGrammes = "SELECT SURNAME ,KATHGORIA, AFM , NAME FROM EMPLOYEE LIMIT ?,? ";
try {
    st = connection.prepareStatement(sqlGrammes);
    st.setInt(1, timh1); // notice the setInt
    st.setInt(2, timh2); // here too
```

Answer (score -3):

I was able to do it without prepared statement

```
int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    sql = "Select SURNAME ,KATHGORIA, AFM , NAME FROM EMPLOYEE limit "+i+ ","+j;
```

got first row as output.

Comment: Be-aware of SQL Injection